# Return URL in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.AuthenticationFailed

Tags: active-directory, owin, azure-active-directory

My website always requires some query parameters. On `OWIN` authentication failure I want to redirect to my home page with some query parameters. The required URL I want to redirect to is in the request URL.

To put it in a different way I want to redirect to the same URL whether my authentication is successful or not.

Is there a clean way I can access the return URL from the `AuthenticationFailedNotification` and do

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
```